# Kendo Dropdown Not Retaining Value After PostBack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo Dropdown that I'm loading using WebApi.
User selects an option from the dropdown and hits search button that does a postback action.
The selection is visible in the controller on the POST action but when the page reloads after postback, the dropdown has lost its selection and is blank now.

How can I have the value selected in dropdown on page reload ?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">  
            @(Html.Kendo()  
            .DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId)  
            .DataTextField("Name")  
            .DataValueField("Id")  
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })  
            .Value("TEST")  
            .AutoBind(false)  
            .Filter("contains")  
            .MinLength(3)  
            .DataSource(source =>  
            {  
                source.Read(read =>  
                {  
                        read.Url("/api/GetNames/" + @Model.PersonnelId);  
                })  
                .ServerFiltering(true);  
            })
            ) 
</div>  
<div>  
<button name="Search" value="true" type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>  
</div>  
</div>
```

I was wondering if on postback, I can use the SelectedId to find the "Name" and show it selected by assigning in .Value() property of dropdown after postback. To test this, I first hardcoded value "TEST" in the dropdown, but I don't see it selected anytime (on first time load or on reload).

Initially I thought it is because of Autobind(true), so I've set it to false so that dropdown loads only after user starts typing. That still hasn't helped with retaining the selection when value is loaded from controller.

Comment: Using `.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId)` should directly bind to the value of SelectedId. Is the SelectedId property passed back to the View updated with the selected value?

Comment: Yes, When page reloads, I see it selected for a split second and the value is no longer there after dropdown refresh (due to webapi call after page refresh). I set the AutoBind to false and then value no longer shows.

Comment: Under the hood `DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId)` basically generates `DropDownList().Name("SelectedId").Value(Model.SelectedId)` The DataValueField configuration indicates the field of the data item that provides the value of the widget. So you can try:
 * remove the `.Value()`
 * check if the response contains a dataItem with the selected value. If not the option label will  be displayed. [example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/QQkJnlvw37TdGSzY18)
 * check the serialization of the response